# Is there a way of preventing other Finder windows from responding to unnecessary drag/drop events?

Tags: finder, windows, macos

[MacOS 10.13.1]
I'm organising some files and have two Finder windows open so I can move files from one to the other.
Since the filename doesn't always describe the contents of the file, I am renaming many of these files after reviewing them and before I moving them.  Renaming the file in Finder window #1 causes the file to be automatically be placed in its correctly sorted position in the file list.  Whilst I understand the behaviour, it then forces me to scroll down to find the file I want to move. *This is getting rather tedious for the number of files I'm dealing with.*

However, what is really irritating me is that after I drop the file into a folder displayed in Finder window #2, Finder window, #2, updates its view to match what Finder window #1 is showing.  This forces me to perform a scroll operation in Finder window #2 to return to the location I was at, before I can move the next file. This is a really frustrating behaviour that is demolishing any sense of efficiency in doing this task.

I'm aware that Mac OS has a `save-as-you-go` behaviour designed into it, which **occasionally** is useful, after all it's not that often that my hard disk crashes or I loose power to my PC.

Nevertheless, is there a way of turning off the behaviour described above, or opening a Finder window that only responds to its own user interactions?

Comment: Maybe slightly quicker, in folder 1, rename foo to bar, bar is still selected. Cmd/c then click folder 2. Cmd/alt/v will move bar to 2. Click back in 1, type foo & you’re back in position.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that (twice) but my Finder has hung up with the spinning wheel of death after the Cmd/alt/v.  :(

Comment: Bizarre... I use that all the time for moving my photos from import to project folders.

Answer (score 2):

Sort differently. If you sort by say, file size, the sort order won't change with the file name. I also enable "date added" or "date created" because those are not the same as "date modified". You can do grouping and sorting through the view menu.